# $\lim_{x\to a}c=c$. Can someone convince me this is true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Why does
$$
\lim_{x\to a}c=c
$$
hold true?

A visual explanation would be greatly appreciated.

My understanding of a limit is the limit is a rule; thus the number it approaches is the range of inputs to an intended height which is the output.

Let me be clear, your outputs are based on your domain, and your domain is defined by what "x is approaching" for a specific limit within a coordinate plane.

Am I on the right track in my thinking?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to c} c = c$ or $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$

Comment: No I mean the limit, as x approaches a of c = c

Comment: The limit of what? Function, sequence, series?

Comment: Wow. You'd think with $>90$ questions under your belt that you would know how to [typeset questions correctly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I agree with @Alex. Your question doesn't make any sense as it is currently being posed.

Comment: I have attached a picture to clarify my question.

Comment: Does your question concern 3, 7, or 8? **None** of them have $x\to c$.

Comment: If you mean point 8, it's exactly what I wrote with $f=x$

Comment: Those pictures just show some very basic results, and doesn't really help in understanding your question.

Comment: Based on the rules I have attached as pictures, why is rule 7 true?

Comment: Using the definition of limit it's quie easy to see why rule 7 is true.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem worth proving rigorously, but who knows...maybe it will help.

**Claim:**
$$
\lim_{x\to a}c=c.
$$

*Proof.* Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|c-c|<\epsilon$. But $|c-c|=0$. Thus, this will be true no matter what $\delta$ we pick. $\Box$

Comment: @Henrik You know what the *real* question is? Who upvoted OP's question??

Comment: Do you have a problem with the question? Also, therapist, you are assuming I have a thorough understanding of absolute values when you utilize it to define my question on limits. Indeed, it would seem if you truly wanted to add knowledgeable information you would have kept your explanation in line with my coordinate  system lead. Your answer is not helpful-

Comment: @Cetshwayo Lol! At first I started to get offended, but then you made me laugh because of how absolutely ludicrous that comment is.

Comment: @Cetshwayo "you would have kept your explanation in line with my coordinate system lead" -- what does that *mean*? I don't even know how to interpret that.

Comment: I would understand any answer to my question better if it was answered with a coordinate system analogy or description. Thanks.

Comment: @therapist: I have pretty much given up on understading the question.

Comment: @Henrik I think you understand the question, certainly, but I don't think *anyone* understands what the OP is struggling with exactly. Or am I off-base?

Comment: @Cetshwayo: If you don't understand therapist's answer, what is your definition of limit?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Draw a horizontal line, any line you please, in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Such a line will be of the form $f(x)=c$, where $c$ is a constant. Now take the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$, where $a$ is *any* number in $\mathbb{R}$. What do you get?

Comment: @Henrik If my last comment does not register...I think I may have sad day.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can think to a function that has constant value. i.e.:
$$
f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad f(x)=c
$$
So now you can write your limit as 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=c
$$
And this simply means that a constant function is continuous, i.e. that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ the value and the limit of the function coincide.

The rigorous proof of this intuitive statement is in the answer of @therapist.

Comment: What does the upside 'A' next to the 'a' an element of real numbers mean?

Comment: @Cetshwayo $\forall$ means "for all." Also, $\exists$ means "exists."